# Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: excel: range has a bad size. it must be only 1 line or 1 row

Tags: excel, range, size, cplex

How can I solve this error? (There is no specific location given)

"Exception from IBM ILOG Concert: excel: range has a bad size. it must be only 1 line or 1 row."

I read my data from Excel. I already wrote my whole code while sheetreading matrices with multiple rows or columns. Never had a problem, now all of a sudden, this pops up as a problem. The last piece of code I did was this

```
forall (d in decisions, o in orders, p in pieces, m in modes) (varcost[d] == (sum (o in orders, p in pieces, m in modes) volume[o]*cvarcalm[m]*distance[p]*z[d,o,p,m]));
```

so my best guess is that this has something to do with it.

You can find my full code here:

https://1drv.ms/w/s!AmJYk6YmU7wu7RgwYjV9U-CqAF-d?e=B9hqbV

Comment: Hi, at least can you share a small sample that will generate that error ?

Comment: I edit the post so you can see the code, thanks in advance

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you could share  .mod .dat and xls at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/home

Comment: I reworked a little bit and now the problem is not the weird error anymore, but CPLEX simply does not return a solution. Can you help me with that? This is new code
https://1drv.ms/w/s!AmJYk6YmU7wu7SA9I11EYhScW1n8?e=YtTjkN

This is the small part I changed. 

forall (d in decisions, o in orders) p[d,o] + deliverytime[o] == sum(p in pieces, m in modes) (time[p,m]*z[d,o,p,m]); 

forall (d in decisions, o in orders) (p[d,o]<=0) => (p[d,o] == 0);

forall (d in decisions, s in scenarios) (penaltycost[d] == sum ( o in orders) cp*p[d,o]);

Answer (score 0):

so then the problem you face is different: you do not get any solution and you need to understand why.

If you name your constraints then CPLEX could help you by giving relaxations and conflicts that will help you.

For instance

```
dvar int x;
dvar int y;

subject to
{
  x==y;
  x!=y;
}
```

does not give any solution whereas

```
dvar int x;
dvar int y;

subject to
{
  ct1:x==y;
  ct2:x!=y;
}
```

gives some info that there is a conflict between ct1 and ct2